# Removing Symlinked Fonts in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts, symbolic-link

I recently had a copy of Extensis Suitcase blow up on me and I need to delete some symlinked font files so I can remove my font vault.

What's the best way to do this?

Some links I was able to manually remove, but others are being more stubborn.

Comment: Stubborn, how? Any errors?

Comment: I hit delete and they do not delete. No errors, they just stay there.

Comment: Try running chkdsk.

Comment: Tried running chkdsk with no improvement. Also tried using Junction Link Magic, but the links do not show up although they are visible in the fonts folder and prevent Suitcase's font vault from being moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ultimately ended up solving the problem was deleting references to the fonts located in the registry under

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software/Microsoft/Windows NT/Current Version/Fonts